# Run a query in every table that contains a specific column

Tags: sql-server

I run this query to get all the tables that include a specific column name

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%myColumn%'
```

Then, for every single table, I want to run a query like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myColumn = xxx
```

Is there any way to do it automatically and run the second query to all the tables from the first query?

I have a fairly big database and I want to check if there is anywhere stored something about the specific Id on myColumn. And this column is used in about 200 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use dynamic query for this. in this I saved the Schema result in a table variable and then loop through them to generate the required query. please try the below:

```
DECLARE @Template varchar(max)='SELECT * FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE [COLUMN_NAME] = ''xxx''';
DECLARE @CMD varchar(max);
DECLARE @id int=1, @TABLE_NAME varchar(255), @COLUMN_NAME varchar(255)

declare @Table table(id int identity(1,1), COLUMN_NAME varchar(255), TABLE_NAME varchar(255))

    INSERT INTO @Table (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME)
    SELECT  TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Label%'


    SELECT @id=ID, @TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME = COLUMN_NAME FROM @Table WHERE ID = @id
    While @@ROWCOUNT>0 BEGIN
        SET @CMD = REPLACE(@Template, '[TABLE_NAME]', @TABLE_NAME)
        SET @CMD = REPLACE(@CMD, '[COLUMN_NAME]', @COLUMN_NAME)
        Print @cmd
        EXEC (@CMD)
        SELECT @id=ID, @TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME = COLUMN_NAME FROM @Table WHERE ID = @id + 1
    End
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I added a couple things to it and posted as a separate answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60626767/5344430

If they are useful feel free to bring them into the original and I'll delete mine

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as follows. The script builds all the SELECT statements in a VARCHAR and then executes dynamically. Works when you for integers as well as varchars.

---

```
DECLARE @col_name SYSNAME='myColumn';
DECLARE @expected_value NVARCHAR(256)='xxx';
DECLARE @sel_stmts NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT 
        ';SELECT '+
            '* '+
        'FROM '+
            QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_NAME) +
        'WHERE '+
            QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME)+'='''+REPLACE(@expected_value,'''','''''')+''''
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c ON
            c.TABLE_SCHEMA=t.TABLE_SCHEMA AND
            c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE
        t.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND
        c.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%'+@col_name+'%'
    FOR
        XML PATH('')
)+';';

--SELECT @sel_stmts; -- review
EXEC sp_executesql @sel_stmts; -- execute it
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple changes to Ahmed Saeed's answer that were helpful for me so posting them here

1. Adding the schema name for dbs with more than one schema
2. Adding extra [] around the schema/db names in case one of those names is also a keyword
3. Printing the tablename with the results

```
DECLARE @Template varchar(max)='SELECT ''[TABLE_NAME]'' as TableName, * FROM [[DBSCHEMA_NAME]].[[TABLE_NAME]] WHERE [COLUMN_NAME] = ''xxx''';
DECLARE @CMD varchar(max);
DECLARE @id int=1, @DBSCHEMA_NAME varchar(255), @TABLE_NAME varchar(255), @COLUMN_NAME varchar(255)

declare @Table table(id int identity(1,1), COLUMN_NAME varchar(255), TABLE_NAME varchar(255), DBSCHEMA_NAME varchar(255))

    INSERT INTO @Table (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DBSCHEMA_NAME)
    SELECT  TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%colname%'


    SELECT @id=ID, @DBSCHEMA_NAME = DBSCHEMA_NAME, @TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME = COLUMN_NAME FROM @Table WHERE ID = @id
    While @@ROWCOUNT>0 BEGIN
        SET @CMD = REPLACE(@Template, '[TABLE_NAME]', @TABLE_NAME)
        SET @CMD = REPLACE(@CMD, '[COLUMN_NAME]', @COLUMN_NAME)
        SET @CMD = REPLACE(@CMD, '[DBSCHEMA_NAME]', @DBSCHEMA_NAME)
        Print @cmd
        EXEC (@CMD)
        SELECT @id=ID, @DBSCHEMA_NAME = DBSCHEMA_NAME, @TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME = COLUMN_NAME FROM @Table WHERE ID = @id + 1
    End
```